# Is the red beam coming out of CYCLOPS' eye a laser beam?

Tags: marvel, x-men

We have all seen that Cyclops projects a red-coloured beam out of his eyes. What is that red beam. Is it laser or something else?

Comment: No, it is a kinetic force beam from another dimension. It is not hot. More like getting punched really, really hard.

Comment: could you explain 'another dimension'

Comment: The fourth paragraph under "Powers and Abilities" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities).

Comment: Voting this up, it's not such a bad question that it deserves to be buried. I've often wondered what it is myself, and no one's screaming general reference or dupe...

Comment: Nominating this question for re-opening because there's a [consensus](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2400/98) that there shouldn't be any closure of questions that are marked general reference.

Comment: There's an accepted answer and this question was in fact easily answered by a general reference lookup, so why should we reopen it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The red beam coming out of Cyclops' eye isn't electromagnetic radiation, so there's no chance of it being LASER.

From official [Marvel Universe wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Cyclops) (See `Powers` from left column):

> Cyclops possesses the mutant ability to project a **beam of heatless
>   ruby-colored concussive force** from his eyes, which act as
>   inter-dimensional apertures between this universe and another.

Comment: No heat, yet he sometimes has used it to spot-weld things.  I love consistency in my comics.

Comment: @Jeff - [Cold Pressure Welding](http://www.coldpressurewelding.com/cms/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92&Itemid=2&lang=en)